# Zend Framework 2 - Join tables in different databases and schemas

Tags: php, database, zend-framework2

In Zend Framework 2 when I want to make a join between different database tables I have to use the `\Zend\Db\Sql\TableIdentifier` class to avoid an incorrect escaping.

If I do in this way:

```
$select->join(['B' => 'database2.table2'], 'A.id = B.id');
```

It is rendered as:

```
SELECT [..] FROM "table" as "A" INNER JOIN "database2.table2" ON [...]
```

This causes an incorrect quoting `"database2.table2"`

To solve this situation I can do:

```
$tbl2 = new \Zend\Db\Sql\TableIdentifier('table2', 'database2');
$select->join(['B' => $tbl2], 'A.id = B.id');
```

In this way the quoting is correct `"database2"."table2"`

But how can I do if I have to specify the database and also the schema? (for example in ms sql server)

The desired result is `"database2"."dbo"."table2"`

Answer (score 2):

When you're in a method of a table gateway class, you can do this:

```
$table2 = new Zend\Db\Sql\TableIdentifier('table2', 'schema_name'); 
$select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select()
->join($table2, 'table1.field = table2.field', ['fields_from_table2'], 'INNER');

$sql = new Sql($this->tableGateway->getAdapter());
$selectString = $sql->buildSqlString($select);
$result = $adapter->query($selectString, $adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```

If you try to write `database.table` literally, you don't let Zend to know that a `database.table` is what it is. Therefore, Zend will put the current database defined in the adapter that is used from current table gateway factory from Module.php, writing `current_database.database.table`.

This question has the same subject the [zf2 make a join between two different databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830774/zf2-make-a-join-between-two-different-databases/18068129)

Answer (score 0):

The schema is specified in your Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter('database' => 'schemaname'). I think that you can not change the schema by query. You must take a diferent Adapter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but, from what I know you can not join two tables from two different adapter, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Should also work for you. You have to use it with tableGateway

```
use use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Where;

$someCondition=new Where();
$someCondition->equalTo('columnName',$columnValue);
//you can build $this->tableGateway from your DB adapter
$rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) use ($someCondition) {
        $table2forInnerJoin = new \Zend\Db\Sql\TableIdentifier('table2Name', 'table2Database');
        $select->join(array('table2Name'=>$table2forInnerJoin),"table1Name.id = table2Name.id");
        $select->where($someCondition);
});
return $rowset;
```